# Group By in MSSQL with the top 10 rows of each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL query which I use to get some stats (AVG, MAX, MIN and COUNT) of each group in my database. The tables are two. Teams and Users. Each team has many users.

```
SELECT t.id, AVG(u.Age) AS Average, MIN(u.Age) AS Minimum, MAX(u.Age) AS Maximum, COUNT(u.id) AS NumberOfUsers

FROM Teams t 

INNER JOIN Users u ON t.id = u.id

WHERE t.status IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY t.id

ORDER BY Average Desc
```

However, the table Users has another column "Experience" and I want to get the same stats for the top 10 users in each group based on that column.

Any idea?

Comment: Does this really work?  The join condition does not look correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `row_number()`, in this case, I think in a subquery:

```
SELECT t.id, AVG(u.Age) AS Average, MIN(u.Age) AS Minimum,
       MAX(u.Age) AS Maximum, COUNT(u.id) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM Teams t INNER JOIN
     (SELECT u.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY experience DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Users u
     ) u
     ON t.id = u.id  AND -- is this really the right join condition?
        seqnum <= 10
WHERE t.status IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY Average Desc;
```

I suspect that your join conditions are wrong.  I would expect the proper join condition to use something like `u.TeamId` instead of `u.Id`.  If so, you need to change the `partition by` column to be the same as the `join` column.

Comment: It's true that the column names are slightly different but it works. Both my version and your version. So, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's solution looks good, you can also consider DENSE_RANK() or RANK() over ROW_NUMBER() to get "better" realistic stats if experience could be the same for many users.